# Cannot resolve symbol 'ast' - org.hibernate.tool.schema.ast.SqlScriptParserException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am on the project migration from spring-boot 2.x to spring-boot 3.1.2 which inturn update the hibernate version from 5.X to 6.

Got struck on the below import, unable to find the equivalent package and also the new location of this package in hibernate 6.

```
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.ast.SqlScriptParserException;
```

Please help me here to fix this error

[image]

Comment: Remove the errorneous import, and press alt-enter (if it's intellij) in IDE. The IDE will suggest you the correct import

Comment: I tired that @dimirsenZ intellij is not suggesting correct import

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace it with `SqlScriptException` from `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.` because it also extend `HibernateException` and it refer to script exception.

**I think that hibernate developers had an refactoring to project structure.**

I dont see new `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SqlScriptException;` in version < 6.x.

I looked into documentation, deprecated list, removed apis list and migration guide and didnt find anything about  if `org.hibernate.tool.schema.ast` package was removed or not.

Comment: Even I did a round of searches about the "ast" package but couldn't find out anywhere, so I started to HibernateException, but SqlScriptException is closer to SqlScriptParserException.